# How to set a data value after v-if has been resolved

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to do what I would think is rather simple, but I can't seem to find a built-in way to do it. Basically, I have several divs on a page that are using v-if conditions which are acting as filters for data on the page (think about a table with data that is then filtered by select boxes)

Below is a very simplified example, but basically, I'm wanting to set a variable in my data object once a v-if condition is satisfied. Then, if filters change and make a different v-if condition satisfied it would set the same variable to a different value.

I basically want a value that can be changed based on any filters on my page, as long as I have a way to set that value after any given v-if is satisfied.

I was hoping to be able to simply call a method (with an argument passed) once v-if resolved is possible

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  props: { 

  },
  data: {
    showData: 'ABC',
    specificData: "here are some specifics",
    newValue: ''
    
  }
  });
```

```html
<div id ="app">
<div v-if="showData === 'ABC'">
  <!--Here, I want to set newValue to something like 'ROGER' unrelated to ABC-->
  ABC
</div>

<div v-if="showData === '123'">
  <!--Here, I want to set newValue to something like 'SAM' unrelted to 123-->
  123
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This kind of business logic should not be handled in template, but rather in a computed property. The most basic setup would look like:

```js
data(){
  return {
    showData: "ABC"
  }
},
computed: {
  newValue(){
    if (this.showData === "ABC") {
      return "Some derived value"
    }
    return ''
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a watcher on `showData`, and call additional methods when any of the conditions are met.

```js
watch: {
  showData(val){
    if (val === "ABC") {
      this.newValue = "Some derived value"
      this.someOtherMethod()
    }
    // Any other conditions to be checked
    // or simply pass the value further to a method where all the checks are done
    this.checkValue(val)
  }
}
```

Comment: This makes sense for sure, but it still doesn't fully accomplish what I'll need as I grow the page (though I agree it shouldn't be handled in the template. Is there a way that I could at least call a method/function with an argument if the v-if is resolved?

Comment: you can use a watcher for that. see the updated answer